# Merge with jq command the fields of two json files

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

I try to using the jq tools (jq-json-processor) in shell script to merge the fields two json.

Here the content of files:

**First file**

```
{ "username": "Bob",
"password": "verytrickipwd",
"windows": 6}
```

**Second file** (the problem now is I have a new fields)

```
{ "username": "",
"password": "",
"windows": 6,
"doors": 
}
```

my expected result

```
{ "username": "Bob",
"password": "verytrickipwd",
"windows": 6,
"doors": 
}
```

Using this command:
`jq -f file1.json file2.json`

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to "add" two JSON objects.  In your particular case, the following suffices:

```
$ jq --argfile override file1.json '. + $override' file2.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "username": "Bob",
  "password": "verytrickipwd",
  "windows": 6,
  "doors": ""
}
```

If your jq does not support the --argfile option, the following should suffice:

```
$ jq -s add file2.json file1.json
```

Note that in the case of key-name collisions, the contents of the second file (file1.json in this example) will take precedence.

Comment: When I enter the command I get the flowing response: jq: Unknown option --argfile

Comment: "--argfile" is supported in the current "stable" release of jq (version 1.5).  I've added an alternative that should work in all versions of jq. If you are still having trouble, then please specify which version of jq you have access to.

Comment: I use version jq version 1.3

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should do what you requested assuming you correct `file2.json` so that it is valid JSON ("doors" is missing a value), e.g.

```
{
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "windows": 6,
    "doors": "doors"
}
```

and run jq with the `-s` option

```
jq -s -f filter.jq file1.json file2.json
```

where `filter.jq` contains the filter below which uses **reduce** to merge objects by updating only keys the first time they are encountered.

```
reduce .[] as $i (
     {}
   ; reduce ($i|keys[]) as $k (
          .
        ; if .[$k] == null then .[$k] = $i[$k] else . end
     )
)
```